# parsing json with dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, struct, decodable

I have been working on this for a few hours and have not been able to find an answer. I have a JSON with dynamic keys that I am trying to parse into a struct. I thought I could keep it simple but I'm getting serialization errors. Please help - thanks

```
{"rates":{
   "btc":{"name":"Bitcoin","unit":"BTC","value":1.0,"type":"crypto"},
   "eth":{"name":"Ether","unit":"ETH","value":35.69,"type":"crypto"},
}}
```

my stuct

```
struct CryptoCoins: Decodable {
   let rates: [String: [Coin]]
}

struct Coin: Decodable {
   let name: String
   let unit: String
   let value: Double
   let type: String
}
```

my decoder:

```
guard let container = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CryptoCoins.self, from: json) else {
   completion(.failure(.serializationError))  // <- failing here
   return
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're decoding the property `rates` into the wrong type - it's not a dictionary of `String` keys and an **array** of `Coin` values - it's just a single `Coin` value.

```
struct CryptoCoins: Decodable {
   let rates: [String: Coin] // <- here
}
```

---

On a related note, don't hide the error with `try?`. Capture it and log it, if necessary:

```
do {
   let cryptoCoins = try JSONDecoder().decode(CryptoCoins.self, from: json)
   // ..
} catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Then you would have gotten a `typeMismatch` error for `btc` key: `"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."`, which would have at least given you a hint of where to look.

Comment: awesome! thank you! and yes, changing my code to capture the error.